# parsing of an xml document using java

Tags: java, javascript, html, xml, xml-parsing

i have a .xml file which has the value like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<CRAWL>
<NAME>span[class=lrg bold],attr=0</NAME>
<PRICE>span[class~=(?i)(bld lrg red|price)],attr=0</PRICE>
<DESC>div[class=sss],attr=0</DESC>
</CRAWL>
```

for reading this xml file i am using the following code.

```
         NodeList nodes = doc.getElementsByTagName("CRAWL");
             for (int i = 0; i < nodes.getLength(); i++)
               {
                 NodeList name = element.getElementsByTagName("NAME");
         Element line = (Element) name.item(0);

         System.out.println("name: " + line.getFirstChild().getTextContent());
         setName(line.getFirstChild().getTextContent());

         NodeList price = element.getElementsByTagName("PRICE");
         line = (Element) price.item(0);
         System.out.println("price: " + line.getFirstChild().getTextContent());
         setPrice(line.getFirstChild().getTextContent());

         NodeList desc = element.getElementsByTagName("DESC");
         line = (Element) desc.item(0);
         System.out.println("description: " +    line.getFirstChild().getTextContent());
         setDesc(line.getFirstChild().getTextContent());
```

It works fine . but my problem is if i have .xml file which has multiple `<CRAWL>` node then how can i parse both.

```
<CRAWL>
<NAME>span[class=lrg bold],attr=0</NAME>
<PRICE>span[class~=(?i)(bld lrg red|price)],attr=0</PRICE>
<DESC>div[class=sss],attr=0</DESC>
</CRAWL>
<CRAWL>
<NAME>span[class=lrg bold],attr=0</NAME>
<PRICE>span[class~=(?i)(bld lrg red|price)],attr=0</PRICE>
<DESC>div[class=sss],attr=0</DESC>
</CRAWL>
```

after reading the values inside `<CRAWL>    </CRAWL>` i want to read the next `<CRAWL>`  `</CRAWL>`

Comment: XML can have only one root element. Put the both CRWL tag inside a single root element otherwise it would not be a valid XML.

Comment: @sarath you are almost there..Why you are using NodeList for reading name ,price,desc.. only one element of that type there right in crawl tag.. it looks like reading all crawl tags

Comment: @sarath, I would recommend using the javax.xml.xpath APIs in the Java SE 5 and above instead of getElementsByTagName to make your code more readable and easier to maintain